# Label Dependent Covariate in Logistic Regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

Given a sequence of events, I am trying to predict a label for events and I hypothesize that the last time this event occurred with a label $i$ has a bearing on when the next time the label $i$ appears. Is it possible to include a covariate which depends on the label? For example my probability for predicting label $i$ would be $P(x=i|y^i)$ and that for predicting label $j$ would be $P(x=j|y^j)$. This would violate the assumption that $y$ are the independent variables in the model.

Comment: I'm a bit fuzzy on the context of the problem, but are you saying there is an autoregressive relationship? Such as an AR(1) time series model? If so, you need a logistic mixed effects model with an AR(1) covariance structure.